# Set TypeFace for ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have 2 XML file for list View. One for views and other for use first.
note_list.XML is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/allNotes_btn_refresh_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/all_note_refresh_list" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and list_otem.XML is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_lbl_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_lbl_subject"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_lbl_date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in below code, i set adapter for list:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> noteList;
ListView lv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.note_list);
    noteList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String note_id = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_lbl_id)).getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteDetail.class);
            i.putExtra("note_id", note_id);
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);
        }
    });
}

public class LoadAllNotes extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllNotes.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("???? ??? ????...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

            noteList.clear();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            UserFunctions userFunctions = new UserFunctions();

            jSon = userFunctions.getAllNotes(userId);

            Log.i("AllNotes >> jSon >>", jSon.toString());

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                if (jSon.has(KEY_SUCCESS)) {
                    String success = jSon.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if (success.equals("1")) {

                        notes = jSon.getJSONObject("notes");
                        for (int i = 0; i < notes.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = notes.getJSONObject(Integer
                                    .toString(i));

                            Log.i("JSONObject c >>", c.toString());

                            String id = c.getString(KEY_NOTE_ID);
                            String subject = c.getString(KEY_NOTE_SUBJECT);
                            String date = c.getString(KEY_NOTE_DATE);

                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put(KEY_NOTE_ID, id);
                            map.put(KEY_NOTE_SUBJECT, subject);
                            map.put(KEY_NOTE_DATE, date);

                            noteList.add(map);
                        }

                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AllNotes.this,
                            noteList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                                    KEY_NOTE_ID, KEY_NOTE_SUBJECT,
                                    KEY_NOTE_DATE }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.list_lbl_id, R.id.list_lbl_subject,
                                    R.id.list_lbl_date });
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

How can i set type face for TextViews in item_list.XML? I set note_list for content view in java code. so can't access to views of list_item.xml. thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to override the `SimpleAdapter`'s `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method and cast the result to a `TextView`. That should be safe to do for the `R.layout.list_item` layout, although you may want to double check that.

From there, setting a typeface works as usual.

Snippet, to be placed inside an (anonymous) extension of SimpleAdapter:

```
Typeface mTypeface = ... // only needs to be initialised once.

@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView textview = (TextView) view;
    textview.setTypeface(mTypeface);
    return textview;
}
```

If, perhaps at some point in the future, you're going to have a more complex layout made out of more than just a single `TextView`, I'd consider implementing your own extension of `ArrayAdapter`. There are heaps of examples on how to go about that (also look up the ViewHolder/RowWrapper pattern) and it'll give you full control.

---

Edit: example code below.

```
public class TypefacedSimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    private final Typeface mTypeface;

    public TypefacedSimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), /* typeface */);
    }

    @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView textview = (TextView) view;
        textview.setTypeface(mTypeface);
        return textview;
    }
}
```

Copy-paste the class above and make sure to set up the type face field as per your requirements. Then replace the current `SimpleAdapter`; i.e. something like this:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new TypefacedSimpleAdapter(AllNotes.this,
        noteList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
        KEY_NOTE_ID, KEY_NOTE_SUBJECT,
        KEY_NOTE_DATE }, new int[] {
        R.id.list_lbl_id, R.id.list_lbl_subject,
        R.id.list_lbl_date }
);
```

Note that I didn't actually compile or run any of this. I'll leave it up to you to fill in any gaps and/or make corrections.

Comment: I have `The method getView(int, View, ViewGroup) is undefined for the type ListActivity` and `The method getView(int, View, ViewGroup) of type AllNotes must override a superclass method` error.

Comment: @1mohammadi.ir: As already explained in my answer, override that method in **`SimpleAdapter`**, not `ListActivity`. Right now you're doing the latter, which is what the error messages tries to tell you. Either do it anonymously (where you're instantiating `SimpleAdapter`), or create your own subclass for it.

Comment: Can u link me a sample? I try many sample but i understand why i can'y do this. thanks.

Comment: I added some extra code to illustrate the general idea and help you on your way. If that's not working out, then I'd recommend doing a bit more reading into Java and Android. If all else fails, start from scratch and code up your own adapter extension - that's the best way to learn and get to understand the relevant bits and pieces.

Answer (score 1):

I add this below class :

```
public class myAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    public myAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items,
            int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, items, resource, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fontsfolder/B Yekan.ttf");

        TextView lbl_subject = ((TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.list_lbl_subject));
        TextView lbl_date = ((TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.list_lbl_date));

        lbl_date.setTypeface(typeFace);
        lbl_subject.setTypeface(typeFace);

        return view;
    }
}
```

And change code when fill list by this :

```
myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(AllNotes.this, noteList,
        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { KEY_NOTE_ID,
                KEY_NOTE_SUBJECT, KEY_NOTE_DATE },
        new int[] { R.id.list_lbl_id,
                R.id.list_lbl_subject, R.id.list_lbl_date });
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks to @MH. for help

Comment: Just something to keep in mind with above code: it's far from efficient. It's creating the same typeface over and over again with every call to `getView(...)` as well as performing relatively expensive view lookups. I'd strongly consider implementing the [ViewHolder/RowWrapper](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) pattern to optimize this.