# change font in spinner items

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have ArrayAdapter has strings of spinner item's

how to change the code pragmatically

note : I know i should override and implement View .. etc but I need more detail :

```
  Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "extrafine.ttf");  



    String array_spinner[];
    array_spinner=new String[3];
    array_spinner[0]="general";
    array_spinner[1]="quisiton";
    array_spinner[2]="suggsution";

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.spinner1 ); 

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );


        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: The general idea which requires a minimum of programming effort is outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13403769/1029225). Although the example deals with a `ListView`, the same basics apply to a `Spinner`. A custom adapter is, however, always more flexible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like this in your adapter :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spinaca, items) {

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

             Typeface externalFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTCom-Lt.ttf");
             ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);

             return v;
     }


     public View getDropDownView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
              View v =super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

             Typeface externalFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTCom-Lt.ttf");
             ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);

             return v;
     }
};
```

Comment: did you import View in your code. Try writing this in the file  -import android.view.View;

Comment: You will have to write a listener for the spinner for that.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the array adapter, you are passing "android.R.layout.simple_spinner".  This is the default layout for each of the detail lines in the spinner.  You need to provide your own version of this with a textview.  You can then specify the "textSize" attribute on the textview and making it any size you want.

Look at "android.R.layout.simple_spinner" to see what kinds of other changes you can make.  You can even copy that file into your layout directory and use it as the starting point for your changes.

Comment: i mean font custom type not size

Comment: What do you mean by "font custom type"?  Would this be a custom type face or just something like changing to bold?

Comment: i want to use extrafine.ttf