# set typeface on SimpleAdapter Android

Tags: java, android, xml

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    pDialog.dismiss();

    if (status.equals("0")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "gagal menampilkan, restart app",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            dataList,
            R.layout.listitem,
            new String[] { "nama","alamat", "telp","latitude","longitude","jam","distance" },
            new int[] {R.id.nama, R.id.alamat, R.id.telp, R.id.lat, R.id.lon, R.id.jam, R.id.distance }
    );

    lve.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

this activity is running with "list_view" layout, how to set typeface of the "list_item"? i need to do it in java, not in xml to force the typeface.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to create your list_item.xml textview, which you can edit the typeface of with the fontFamily setting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set TypeFace for ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403605/set-typeface-for-listview)