# How to change font of listView in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, listview

following is a code snippet from an app of android where I want to change the font of my listView items. But it doesn't affect:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

Typeface tf= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/JAMEEL.TTF"); 

Paint paint = new Paint(tf);
lv.setPaint(paint);
```

Please tell me how to change the font of listview items.

Comment: you should to define a custom adapter, and inside that put a textview and finally set typeface for that textview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734273/how-to-set-custom-font-for-android-listview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42976600/6478047 , use this method to change font of textview list item

Comment: its not about textview. its about listview

Comment: @TehminaBatool, listview is a viewgroup that contains views you need, such as textview or etc, depends on your design, if you need more search for `listview custom adapter`

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTypeFace()`:

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/JAMEEL.TTF"); 
textView.setTypeFace(type); //listview - textview anything
```

You can also try using [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library which is easier to set fonts for the whole app.

Comment: i am using listview, not textview... these methods are not available for listview

Comment: You'll need to override a method in the `ListView` Adapter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13403769/4409113 But that wasn't my point since you didn't use `setTypeFace()`. Also, it's better to use `RecyclerView` nowadays.

Comment: thanks. how to use calligraphy library for listview. is there any specific tutorial?

Comment: Just add the [dependency](https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy#dependency) and follow the [installation](https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy#installation). It actually explained everything you need :)